# SSO between web application in IBM WAS 7 and ADFS2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, websphere-7, adfs2.0, spring-saml

I have used spring-security-saml2 plugin to establish sso between tomcat web application and ADFS server.  I am trying to achieve the same in a web application deployed in IBM Websphere Application Server 7.

I created a custom keystore in IBM WAS and used that to enable SSL on WAS. The personal certificate of keystore is used in application securityContext.xml to sign the metadata and the signer certificate in imported in ADFS server. The ADFS server certificate is imported as signer certificate into WAS keystore. I am able to send authentication request to ADFS server and also able to view the response in logs.  But getting following error in decoding on the screen.

```
Error 401: Authentication Failed: Error decoding incoming SAML message
```

And in logs:

```
29-09-2015 15:06:25,722 DEBUG org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder:85 - Successfully decoded message.
29-09-2015 15:06:25,722 DEBUG org.opensaml.common.binding.decoding.BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:191 - Checking SAML message intended destination endpoint against receiver endpoint
29-09-2015 15:06:25,722 DEBUG org.opensaml.common.binding.decoding.BaseSAMLMessageDecoder:203 - SAML message intended destination endpoint in message was empty, not required by binding, skipping
29-09-2015 15:06:25,723 DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl:109 - No inbound message in artifact response message.
29-09-2015 15:06:25,724 DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl:122 - Could not decode artifact response message.
org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: No inbound message in artifact response message.
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:110)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.doDecode(HTTPArtifactDecoderImpl.java:94)
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:79)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
```

**In ADFS server logs following error is coming.**

```
The artifact resolution request failed. 

Additional Data 
Exception message: 
MSIS3015: The signing certificate of the claims provider trust '+++++++++++++++++++++' identified by thumbprint '#################' is not valid. It might indicate that the certificate has been revoked, has expired, or that the certificate chain is not trusted.
```

Can somebody help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Websphere SAML TAI to establish SSO with ADFS. Some links I did refer are [developerworks](https://developer.ibm.com/depmodels/cloud/) and [techblog](https://web.archive.org/web/20171101031601/http://techblog.gis-ag.info/2015/07/20/saml-enterprise-sso-in-the-websphere-world/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make IBM WAS as Relying Party in ADFS. When we will implement this setup the outcome/Income claims will be main source for User Profile load for authentication and pass the SAML Response to SP(End URL of your application).

Refer the below links to configure as relying party for ADFS.

https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: Do you mean that if I have multiple web applications (with different URL) in same WAS  I should make IBM WAS as the relaying party not individual applications. I am trying for SP initiated SSO. The web application is added as relaying party on ADFS.

Comment: Even though it's SP initiated. The SP will send authenNrequest and redirect to IDP. IDP will authenticated and will send the SAML response to SP. When we add relaying party in ADFS the Outcome/income claims pass the User profile to IDP from ADFS.

Comment: In this case IDP is ADFS server. I am able to establish trust relationship between ADFS and Web application/SP (deployed on IBM WAS) and send authentication request. The issue is with some certificate may be which I am not able to identify. So I am getting error when decoding artifact response from IDP.

Comment: In that case first turn off the cert validation and test it.

Comment: Where to turn off the cert validation on application side. Do I need to change the securityContext.xml

Comment: You have to disable Cert validation  at SP .The below link will help you to check the cert validation. In that link they have mentioned a tool to validate the cert.                                                                              http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/04/02/saml2-signature-validation-tool-for-saml2-response-and-assertion/

Comment: Sorry, I checked ADFS logs again, from ADFS logs it seems we are not able to establish trust. The confusion is which certificate of WAS should be imported into ADFS.